# MySQL: Temporary Table is empty

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

When creating a temporary table in a stored procedure, the temporary table sometimes is empty once the stored procedure has finished even though the requested data exists.

The following code fragments are narrowed down to the essential information.

First of all, there is a stored procedure collecting data and storing it in a temporary table:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `loadWorkorderData`(
        IN p_workorder VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE workorderData SELECT * FROM measurementdb.fodatmeasurements WHERE fodatmeasurements.workorder=p_workorder;
END
```

In most cases, this works as expected:

```sql
CALL loadWorkorderData('FA21-43280');
Query OK, 12 rows affected (1,44 sec)
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM workorderData;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|       12 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,09 sec)
DROP TABLE workorderData;
```

However, sometimes the temporary table is empty:

```sql
CALL loadWorkorderData('FA21-43272');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,08 sec)
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM workorderData;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,08 sec)
DROP TABLE workorderData;
```

However, data for FA21-43272 exists. When creating the table manually:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE workorderData SELECT * FROM measurementdb.fodatmeasurements WHERE fodatmeasurements.workorder='FA21-43272';
Query OK, 12 rows affected (1,30 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM workorderData;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|       12 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,09 sec)
```

All this happens using the same connection. The creation of the temporary table (i.e. the structure) always works. However data is not always added to the table. There is no error when executing the stored procedure:

```sql
CALL loadWorkorderData('FA21-43272');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,08 sec)
SHOW ERRORS;
Empty set (0,08 sec)
```

What am I missing here or am I probably not seeing the wood for the trees?

**Addition:** Inserting records matching the same constraint into the temporary table after calling the procedure works, too:

```sql
CALL loadWorkorderData('FA21-43272');

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM workorderData;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,08 sec)

INSERT INTO workorderData SELECT * FROM measurementdb.fodatmeasurements WHERE measurementdb.workorder='FA21-43272';

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM workorderData;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|       12 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,11 sec)
```

***Solution:*** Well, it's embarassing. But the problem was a trailing space at the end of the value in the column `workorder`.

Interestingly, a "direct" SELECT-Statement seems to be forgiving regarding the matching:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('_',workorder,'_') FROM fodatmeasurements WHERE workorder='FA21-43272' LIMIT 1;
+---------------------------+
| CONCAT('_',workorder,'_') |
+---------------------------+
| _FA21-43272 _             |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0,33 sec)
```

Comment: If server reports *0 rows affected* then this means that 0 selectable rows which matches the condition exists in a table during the query execution. Check does some concurrent process effects. Check `SHOW WARNINGS;`, for example...

Comment: @Akina ```SHOW WARNINGS``` also does not return any information. As I said (and showed in one snippet) the data matching the condition actually is existing.

Comment: *The creation of the temporary table (i.e. the structure) always works.* Does the structure of created empty temptable matches the structure of the source table? Does the next SELECT INTO successfully inserts 12 rows into this temptable?

Comment: @Akina yes, the structure matches. And yes, a subsequent 'manual' INSERT for the same data works, too.

Comment: Just a suspicion ,do a `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS workorderData;` immediately after BEGIN.

Comment: *yes, the structure matches* This means that the source table (its structure at least) is successfully accessed. But none rows are selected. You show that the fact that none rows is selected is reproduceable (maybe with some probability)... test does you may see the same effect during single SELECT query executed from the same SP instead of CREATE .. INSERT.

Comment: I found the solution. And - of course - it's the most stupid thing to ever happen. I will change the Question accordingly.